# Generic parameter 'Entity' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, syntax

I'm not sure why Swift cannot infer the type that I'm explicitly passing in, as a parameter.

On the fetch manager below, I get an error, when I try to load objects of type 'Entity'.

> generic parameter 'Entity' could not be inferred

```
class EventsViewController: UIViewController {
  private let fetchManager = FetchManager()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchManager.willPerformQuery = {}
    // generic parameter 'Entity' could not be inferred
    fetchManager.loadObjects(ofType: Event) { (outcome) in
      switch outcome {
      case .success(let events):
        print("Entities: \(events.count)")
      case .failure(let code):
        switch code {
        case .connectionUnavailable:
          print("1")
        case .notAuthenticated:
          print("2")
        case .retry:
          print("3")
        case .serviceUnavailable:
          print("4")
        case .unknown:
          print("5")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class FetchManager {
  private let database: ReadableDatabase = CloudKitDatabase()
  var willPerformQuery: () -> Void = {}
  func loadObjects<Entity: Queryable & CloudKitInitable>(ofType type: Entity, withCompletion completion: @escaping (FetchOutcome<Entity>) -> Void) {
    database.loadObjects(matching: Entity.query, willPerformQuery: { [weak self] (_) in
      self?.willPerformQuery()
    }, didPerformQuery: { (outcome) in
      switch outcome {
      case .success(let files):
        let entities: [Entity] = files.compactMap(Entity.init)
        completion(FetchOutcome<Entity>.success(entities))
      case .failure(let code):
        completion(FetchOutcome<Entity>.failure(code))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to reference the type itself (to access its "meta type") is `TypeName.self`. In this case you would use `Event.self`:

```
fetchManager.loadObjects(ofType: Event.self) { (outcome) in 
                                      ^~~~~
```

The method signature should also be updated with `Entity.Type`, so the compiler can tell that it want type `information` not the type `instance`:

```
func loadObjects<Entity: Queryable & CloudKitInitable>(ofType type: Entity.Type, ...) {
...
}
```